# Failed to import module when building the sphinx documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm using `Sphinx` version `1.4.5`.

My project structure is the following:

`+ src > main.py
+ docs (generated with sphinx-quickstart)`

Even after adding the path to the `src` folder in `docs/conf.py`:

```py
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../src'))
```

And generating the rst file for `src/main.py` (i.e. `docs/src.rst` and `docs/modules.rst`) with:

```sh
$ sphinx-apidoc -fo docs src
```

When I try to build the `html` webpages with:

```sh
$ make clean
$ make html
```

It couldn't find both the `src` module and `src/main.py`:

`WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module u'src.main'; the following exception was raised`

Comment: what's is your current working directory? Is it `docs`?

Comment: No it's the parent of both `src` and `docs` (i.e. the project folder).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try doing this for your path insertion instead:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../'))
```

Also consider a better name for your directory than `src`.

Comment: The `conf.py` was generated directly inside the `docs` folder. What do you suggest to use instead of `src`?

Comment: See my update for what you should try if `conf.py` is inside `docs`. wrt directory naming, it's common practice to name your source directory the same as the project - so if your project is called Foobar, have a directory `foobar` instead of `src`.

Answer (score 6):

I like to use the following code in `conf.py` to know exactly what the current directory is and where is the target module (to obtain documentation):

```
current_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
target_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(current_dir, "../../src"))
sys.path.insert(0, target_dir)

print(target_dir)
```

In this case, I'm looking to create documentation for my src, see the tree for context:

```
main
├── docs
│   ├── build
│   ├── make.bat
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── source
│       ├── conf.py
│       └── index.rst
│ 
└── src
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── target_module
    ├── requirements.txt
    └── setup.py
```

Next, from your terminal:

```
[user@localhost docs]$ sphinx-apidoc -f -o source/ ../src/target_module
[user@localhost docs]$ make html
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current working directory should be the directory of your makefile, which should be `docs`.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by working directory? Do you mean the directory where I execute `sphinx-apidoc` and `make`?

Comment: @Hakim yes, in your example it is `./docs/`